# положение UIImageView после scale относительно superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

у меня есть UIImageView которое расположено в UIView
И я делаю этому UIImageView scale до 0.8
и как итог я вижу что UIImageView уменьшается до 0.8 но уменьшается к центру UIView

то что получается сейчас 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что мне нужно получить:
чтобы при scale UIImageView была привязана к низу UIVIew. 
`anchorPoint` как я понимаю не поможет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас макет построен с помощью autolayout?

Comment: @schmidt9 UIImageView вписано в Uiview с помощью autolayout

Comment: а как именно? Какие констрейнты установлены?

Comment: У вас на второй картинке нижний отступ нулевой, а на первой нет, то есть нижний отступ не должен сохраняться при масштабировании?

Comment: @schmidt9 установлены констрейнты все по 0. Со всех сторон. Да. Мне нужно чтобы нижний отступ не сохранялся при масштабировании.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью трансформов, при этом должны быть известны конечные размеры вью, поэтому вызываем например во `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` вью контроллера. Сначала мы делаем сдвиг и потом масштабируем

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        scaleImage()
    }

    func scaleImage() {
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.8
        let initialHeight = imageView.frame.height
        let finalHeight = initialHeight * scale
        let translationY = (initialHeight - finalHeight) / 2
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: translationY).scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
    }
```